# Use GitHub Pages domain for a Netlify site

Tags: github-pages

I would like to build a [Netlify](http://netlify.com/) (or perhaps a [Zeit Now](https://zeit.co/now)) site.

Despite the extra feaures of Netlify and Zeit, I find [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/)  `foo.github.io` domain name more catchy than `foo.netlify.com`.

I see that GitHub allows to use a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain), so that you can point your `example.com` domain to your GitHub pages.

Is the reverse possible? That is, I'd like   using  `foo.github.io`  as the domain name for the site stored at `foo.netlify.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do now *own* the domain `github.io` (and by extension, the domain foo.github.io) this is not feasible.

To add a [custom domain to Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/custom-domains/), you need to point a `CNAME` to [your-random-string-url.netlify.com](https://your-random-string-url.netlify.com) (via DNS).

GitHub allows you to [redirect a domain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/redirects-on-github-pages), but this will rewrite the *url* in the browser - which is not what you want.

I would recommend investing in your own domain name, and point it to whichever service you end up using. You will then not be locked into any service in the future.